# How would I set up a hexagonal-shaped map using Javascript and hex tiles?

Tags: javascript

I've got the basic math done for a standard "square" hexagon map, however I would like to convert this to a hex-shaped map in full, one that appears as a hexagon made out of hexagons. For Javascript however, I am unsure of how to do this using the code I've built already - here's what I have so far:

```
function CreateHexGrid()
{
    for (x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        tileArray[x] = [];

        for (y = 0; y < mapWidth; y++)
        {
            var hex = new hexTile(game, 0, 0);
            var point = calculateGrid(x,y);
            hex.x = point.x;
            hex.y = point.y;
            gameContainer.add(hex);
            hex.tileColor = returnRandomHex();
            hex.switchSprite(hex.tileColor);

            tileArray[x][y] = hex;

        }
    }
}

function calculateGrid(x, y)
{
    var point = new PIXI.Point(x,y);

    var offset = 0;

    if (point.y % 2 != 0)
    {
        offset = 90 / 2;
    }

    var x = offset + point.x * 95;
    var y = point.y * 100 * 0.75;

    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;

    return point;
}
```

This is my end goal:

[image: Hexagon]

I have attempted to convert code from an apparent C/++/# example initially found on [RedBlobGames](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html), however it gave me a very strange rectangular trapezoid shape once I actually got the coordinates in:

```
for (int q = -map_radius; q <= map_radius; q++) {
    int r1 = max(-map_radius, -q - map_radius);
    int r2 = min(map_radius, -q + map_radius);
    for (int r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
        map.insert(Hex(q, r, -q-r));
    }
}
```

I would rather do this without having to tell it to 'not draw' various offset sections outside the wanted shape - what I'd consider an "edited" map after the fact of it being drawn.

This is my converted version for Javascript following examples provided by RBG and StackExchange so far:

```
for (q = 0; q < mapRadius; q++)
{
    for (r = 0; r < mapRadius; r++)
    {
        var point = calculateGrid(-q-r, r);
        var hex = new hexTile(game, point.x, point.y);
        gameContainer.add(hex);
    }
}
```

When I follow the examples provided for a hexagonal map, this is the result that I am getting:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I've been trying to follow and use in JS. Strangely enough, following some of the code examples produces the wrong shape.

Comment: Drop the if (point.y % 2 != 0)
    {
        offset = 90 / 2;
    } from your code and use my transform instead.

Comment: I'm getting the above if I remove my coordinates and use it - with or without the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple code to compute the positions of each cell for such an hexagonal arrangement.

```
function hexGrid(edgeLength){
    var len = 2*edgeLength - 1,
        vx = Math.sin(Math.PI/6), vy = Math.cos(Math.PI/6),
        tl = edgeLength - 1, br = 3*edgeLength - 2,
        positions = [];

    for(var y = 0; y < len; ++y){
        for(var x = 0; x < len; ++x){
            //you may want to remove this condition
            //if you don't understand the code
            if(x+y < tl || x+y >= br) continue; 
            positions.push({
                x: vx*y + x,
                y: vy*y
            });
        }
    }
    return positions;
}
```

It expects the length of the outer edge for your grid, and returns an array of positions for the cells.

This is just the basic Math to arrange the cells, since this seems to be your core problem. You'll have to scale and translate/offset the points according to your needs, but that's up to you.

A sandbox to play a bit around: https://jsfiddle.net/36bjmtax/1/

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the positioning has been my biggest problem with this. Math is not my strong point - but I love logic and code and can put quite a lot together with the logic side of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a different method for coordinates then you get a diamond shaped area which is close to your goals. The coordinates would start with (0,0,0) which each coordinate having a sum of zero. In x direction, add (1,0,-1) in the y-ish direction add (0,1,-1). Then from painting, exclude those with x+y < 3 and x+y > 11. Or talking in z-values, paint only -11 < z and z < -3.

How about this for the second method of painting:

```
int map_side = 4;
for (int q = 0; q < map_side; q++) {
    for (int r = 0; r < map_side; r++) {
        if( -map_side >= -q-r && -q-r > -3*map_side)
            map.insert(Hex(q, r, -q-r));
    }
}
```

Sorry for the sloppy code, its not easy to code blind without off by one errors. For the translation of coordinate systems you can use:

```
function hexToXY(hex) {
    var xy = new Point(hex.X * 7 + hex.Y * 5, hex.Y * 5);
    return xy;
}
```

Comment: I added some additional information and an example that I've already attempted to convert between languages.